# Why does gmail send confirmation mail to address of alias?

Tags: gmail, alias

When I'm trying to create an alias in gmail, it sends a confirmation email to that address (to the alias that I'm trying to create).
And then of course it says that there is no such address. Of course, it's just an alias that I'm actually trying to create.

An alias - is an alternative email address which is used with the same email account. Here is [Google docs](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33327?hl=en) about it.

In outlook I could do it easily. It worked as expected: I assigned an alternative email address to the existing abount, without creating any new email accounts, and all mails from all aliases go to one mailbox.

In gmail I go to **Settings**, **Accounts and Import,** **Add Another email address,** typing *name* and *email address* (that I want to be my new alias) and then there is a button appear on the next step: **Send Verification.**

Comment: What do you mean by "alias"? What steps are you following to create the "alias"?

Comment: @ Rubén I updated it.

Comment: Thank you for let me know that you updated the question. The docs linked are for G Suite accounts and the instructions there are for G Suite admins. Are you using a G Suite account? Are you a G Suite admin?

Comment: @Rubén no, I don't.

Comment: Google, in their attempt to use a simple language on docs for end-user , is known for being ambiguous across their services. I suggest you to look at the docs on https://support.google.com/mail instead of the docs on https://support.google.com/a as the last are pointed to G Suite administrators while the first are pointed to Gmail users.

Comment: @Rubén screw them, still can't find necessary information in there. Easier just to use Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

Gmail (for email addresses hosted on gmail.com) allows "plus" aliases that doesn't require a verification email. For all other "aliases", specially those added by using "Settings, Accounts and Import, Add Another email address" requires a email verification. Why? That is a Google policy.